# Do I need resistors or capacitors on this relay?

Tags: relay, electronics, switch

I'm using my Arduino to control a relay switch, which has an extension cord attached to it (see photo).

The relay is connected to the Arduino via pin 9, which is set to `pinMode(9, OUTPUT);`

Do I need any resistors or capacitors or diodes attached to this? Almost feels *too* simple, given I'm running AC power through the relay. But maybe no?

It definitely *works*, but I want to make sure I'm not going to burn something out (or down).

[image]

Comment: Majenko's answer describes how to switch a relay. However DO NO DO THIS. Breadboards are not designed for mains voltages or currents. If you are playing with mains power you need proper isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is too simple.

The Arduino's IO pin is not designed to directly drive a relay. It needs to go through a transistor first, and you must include a diode to absorb the back-EMF generated by the collapsing magnetic field.

Google for "Arduino Relay" and you will find hundreds of thousands of examples.

In short, the circuit you need to create is this:

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of the transistor?

Comment: It acts as a switch turning the relay on and off.

Comment: Is that not the function of the Arduino? Sending `digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);` through one of the pins to the relay switches the relay.

Comment: No. The arduino isn't powerful enough to switch a relay reliably. It can switch the transistor and then the transistor switches the relay. Technically the transistor is acting as a *current amplifier*..

Comment: I'm definitely successfully switching the relay with just the Arduino. So, if it's functioning, is there any real reason to use the transistor (for, say...safety purposes)?

Comment: The key word that I used was **reliably**. You are most likely drawing too much current from the port for sustained operation. That is bad. You have no back emf protection. That is even worse. I'd give it a week tops before you have to throw your Arduino away.